# Python: how to compute the spatial autocorrelation of indicators from a shapefile?

Tags: python, pandas, pysal

I am using `geopandas` to read the shapefile of municipalities of Switzerland, i.e `municipalities.shp`. For 170 I have the info of the population, i.e. `population.csv` The files from can be found in this repo [here](https://github.com/emanuelemassaro/shapeFiles).

Is it possible to merge the information trough the so called `BFS number`.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas

mun = geopandas.read_file('municipalities.shp')
pop = pd.read_csv('population.csv')
## merge data
mergedData = pd.merge(mun,pop,left_on='BFS_NUMMER',right_on='BFS')
```

Now for each of the 170 municipalities I have the geographic information and the info of the population.

I would like to know if I can use `pysal` to check if the population of these 170 municipalities is spatially autocorrelated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. First of all you need to be sure that you are passing geodataframe, your code is returning pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

mun = gpd.read_file('municipalities.shp')
pop = pd.read_csv('population.csv')
# merge data
mergedData = mun.merge(pop,left_on='BFS_NUMMER',right_on='BFS')
```

Then you can work with `pysal`'s tools. I will be using `libpysal` and `esda` packages following new structure of `pysal`.

```
import libpysal
import esda

weights = libpysal.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(mergedData)  # generate spatial weights (Queen in this case)
spatial_auto = esda.Moran(mun[['population']], weights)  # calculate Moran's I
```

First you have to generate spatial weights matrix. If you want to use different than Queen, just follow https://libpysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html. Then you generate Moran's I index of spatial autocorrelation (global). It generates all the attributes you might need (https://esda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/esda.Moran.html#esda.Moran). Similar syntax would be for Gamma, Geary's C or Getis Ord autocorrelation indices.

Documentation for `esda` is really good, showing examples in jupyter notebooks, I recommend to check that for other info (like local autocorrelation or plotting) - https://esda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Is there a way to calculated spatial correlation between points? It seems this method requires polygons

Comment: There is, you just need to define spatial weights matrix in some way. You can certainly use `libpysal.weights.DistanceBand`, `libpysal.weights.Kernel` or `libpysal.weights.KNN` to do that. Example above is using Queen, which is contiguity-based method depending on polygons. Those listed are distance based, so they work on points as well.